# I can't run MySQL server on xampp on Windows 10

Tags: mysql

Every time I want to run MySql server on xampp there occurs the same error Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

I tried to change port for MySQL server in my.ini and in xampp config. Same error.
I'm running the program as a administrator of course.
I tried to run after I deleted ib_logfiles in data in mysql folder.
Same error.

Here's the text from error.log:

```
2019-05-25 00:48:27 2980 InnoDB: Warning: Using 
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed 
in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and 
with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm 
has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to 
use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count 
buffer 
pool pages

2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is 
disabled
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows 
interlocked functions
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() 
are used for memory barrier
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 
1.2.11
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 
16.0M
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of 
buffer pool
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file 
D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [ERROR] InnoDB: os_file_set_size() of file 
D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to 5242880 bytes failed with 6
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot set log file 
D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to size 5 MB
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned 
error.
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a 
STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: 
InnoDB
2019-05-25  0:48:27 10624 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Looks similar to this (different OS though) - https://serverfault.com/questions/379714/unknown-unsupported-storage-engine-innodb-mysql-ubuntu

Comment: None of the suggestions in linked thread helped me.